# background change width if over javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, css

hello I have postet I don't know over 20 posts but nobody has understand me hahah -.-

so i have "draw" a structure I think thats the easiest way to let you understand my problem, because i can't write javascript or jquery so i hope you can help me...

idea then a var is coming over main.js '(var 323) then ask for the subfolder if exist

change the value  of var 1 to var 323

else change the value of var 1 to "default";

```
('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript">value 1</script>/1.jpg;')
```

heres the structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/b22sj.png

[image]

can you make a reconstruction of this :/ ?

Comment: we still didn't understand hahahaha X( ..

Comment: look at the picture there you see what for script i am looking for haha ://

Comment: It's now clear with the image. Thank you for the effort. But how you fill the mpname variable?

Comment: @user3226070 not sure if I could delete the ('backgrounds/<script type="...) that makes it more confusing, could you please edit your question and if that is not needed, remove it pleae, and please also remove the link from "heres the strcuture->..." thanks

Comment: so the idea is mpname is a value that javascript get from the server so its a mapname and to every mapname i make a subfolder with background pics  and now then a map is in the value i will that javascript check if for this map exist a subfolder .. if not then use the "derfault" subfolder

Comment: Yes, understood! It's easier to check it on the server side! Example:

`if(file_exits('backgrounds/[your_value_here]/1.jpg')) {
    $path = 'backgrounds/[your_value_here]/1.jpg';
} else {
    $path = 'backgrounds/default/1.jpg';
}`

and in your `style.php` simply write : 

`{background: url('<?php echo $path ?>')};`

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions :

1. You are in need to generate style rule using php script.
2. Depending on a decision, you need to pick a background image and apply to an element.

Points:

1. Your `php` file should contain a function which returns the final style rule.
2. You will call that function in you `.js` file like this:

`var element = document.getElementById("your_element_id_for_which_
you_are_trying_change_background");
element.style.background = url("<?php $that_function_which_returns_image_path ?>");`

Finally, Forget about that external `style.php` you are trying to make.

You know ? *Style sheets end with `.css` extention as a convention*

Comment: its complicated have you skype'? :S then  i can show everything

Comment: also the system is comlpicated

Comment: I am sorry I was away. Okay show me if I know, I will tell you. myskype: `sivtumma`